# Tomcat 8 won't start on ubuntu

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu

I do have a problem with Tomcat 8 installation on Ubuntu 15.10
That's what I've done:

- I downloaded last version: apache apache-tomcat-8.0.32.tar.gz
- Unpacked it in /var/local/
- on shell:

  /var/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/bin/startup.sh

and I got this

```
    Using CATALINA_BASE:   /var/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.32
    Using CATALINA_HOME:   /var/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.32
    Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /var/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/temp
    Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
    Using CLASSPATH:       /var/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/bin/bootstrap.jar:/var/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
    Tomcat started.
```

I thought it was running on port 8080 so I checked

```
    sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 8080
```

and I got

```
    tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1203/apache2
```

but if on browser I go on localhost:8080 I got:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server. Apache/2.4.12
>   (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 8080

Any clues?

**EDIT:**
I Checked my port in /var/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/conf/server.xml and I changed it in 8080, then I restarted Tomcat.
If now I want to check my port 8080

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 8080
```

I don't see anything

**EDIT 2**

This is my server.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8080" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: check your server port in below file `/var/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/conf/server.xml`

Comment: I did, my server port was 8005 but I changed it in 8080.

Comment: have you checked your catalina logs ??

Comment: I don't know how to check catalina logs

Comment: use below command to see your catalina logs and paste here `tail -f /var/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/logs/catalina.out`

Comment: at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:703)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:664)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

Comment: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

Comment: at the end of logs is there any line saying ` Server startup in....`

Comment: paste your server.xml file content

Comment: I edited the question (EDIT 2) because it was too long for a comment

Comment: Edit your server.xml do this change `<Server port="8085" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">` then restart your tomcat server and try to access you server url with port 8080 e.g. `http://server-ip:8080/`

Comment: one more thing have to configure java path???

Answer (score 0):

The error message you got does seem to reveal the identity of the server that is issuing this message : "Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) Server".

That is NOT your Tomcat server.  That is httpd.  Port 8080 is the installation default for many engines, but of course only a single one of them can use it.  To change this value for the tomcat installation, locate the server.xml file in the conf directory.  Edit that file, replacing 8080 by a port number of your choice where applicable.

Comment: The thing is, if I do netstat -tulpn | grep 8080, I don't get any answer, so I guess port 8080 is closed

Comment: doesn't netstat have a -a option that will display all listening sockets ?